# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameter'

Tags: c#, oracle, oracle11g

I am using oracle function to insert data from c# windows forms into my oracle database and of course i need to use **"Oracle Data Access Component"** 
oracle documentation said that decimal data type C# is equal to number data type column in oracle database..

so whats wrong with below code !

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type
>   'Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameter'.

```
string connstr = @"Data Source=orcl; User Id=user; password=admin;";

string insertcmdtxt = @"F_INSERT_ORDER_DATA";   //~ F_INSERT_ORDER_DATA ~//

using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(connstr))
using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(insertcmdtxt, conn))
{
    try
    {
        conn.Open();

        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        cmd.CommandText = insertcmdtxt;

        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("P_CUSTOMER_ID", OracleDbType.Decimal).Value = TB_CUSTOMER_ID.Text);

        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("P_NOTES", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = TB_NOTES.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(":vORDER_ID", OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterDirection.ReturnValue);

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


        TB_INVOICE_ID.Text = (cmd.Parameters[":vORDER_ID"].Value).ToString();
    }
    catch (Exception EX)
    {
        textBox1.Text = insertcmdtxt;
        MessageBox.Show(EX.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        textBox1.Text = EX.Message;
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: the value 1000 came from cust_id.text but I replaced by 1000 for testing sorry I forgot to replace it back before posting

Answer (score 0):

`Value = 1000` returns an integer and the `Add` method expects an object of type `OracleParameter`. You have two options, either to separate the initialization from setting the value:

```
var paramCustomerId = new OracleParameter("P_CUSTOMER_ID", OracleDbType.Decimal);
paramCustomerId.Value = Decimal.Parse(TB_CUSTOMER_ID.Text);

cmd.Parameters.Add(paramCustomerId);
```

Or as a shortcut that is not that much readable, you can do this:

```
var paramCustID = new OracleParameter("P_CUSTOMER_ID", OracleDbType.Decimal);
cmd.Parameters.Add(paramCustID).Value = Decimal.Parse(TB_CUSTOMER_ID.Text);
```

You need to do the same for the 2 other parameters.

Comment: Your first para is stil kind of misleading

Comment: the value 1000 came from cust_id.text but I replaced by 1000 for testing sorry I forgot to replace it back before posting

Comment: @samer this is not the problem. Whether integer or any other type, you need to know that `Add()` method expects an `OracleParameter` object and not `Value = whatever`

Comment: @samer You code is as if you're writing : `cmd.Parameters.Add(1000)` so the compiler is generating an error that you can't convert 1000 to type `OracleParameter` . Check the edited answer on how to convert the input to decimal.

Comment: I am facing same errors i was faced before posting here now I got error said " Input string was not in a correct format."

Comment: @samer because the input in not a decimal. What is the value inside `TB_CUSTOMER_ID` ?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are suppose to do

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("P_CUSTOMER_ID", OracleDbType.Decimal)).Value = 1000;
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("P_NOTES", OracleDbType.Varchar2)).Value = TB_NOTES.Text;
```

Notice the difference in the placement of the closing parenthesis `)`

Comment: the value 1000 came from cust_id.text but I replaced by 1000 for testing sorry I forgot to replace it back before posting

Comment: Is the error gone? I think the error might still persist even if you just replace the 1000 to txtBox.text

Comment: I am facing same errors i was faced before posting here now I got error said " Input string was not in a correct format."

Comment: That is different error. Have u tried ` Convert.ToDecimal()` method

Answer (score 0):

The reason you cannot call `Add` like that is the type of the assignment expression: when you write

```
something = 123
```

(in this case, `something` is `Value` property of the newly created object) the type of the assignment expression is the type of the value being assigned, i.e. an `int`.

You should be able to do it using initializer syntax:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(
    new OracleParameter("P_CUSTOMER_ID", OracleDbType.Decimal) {
        Value = 1000M // "M" makes decimal
    }
);
```

Now the type of the expression remains `OracleParameter`, which lets you proceed with the call.

You can change the type of the value from an `int` to a `decimal` by appending an `M` suffix to it.

Comment: the value 1000 came from textbox.text but I replaced by 1000 for testing

Comment: @samer Then you should replace it with `decimal.Parse(textbox.Text)`

Comment: i get back to error Input string was not in a correct format.

Comment: @samer Then you need to debug this issue first. Set a breakpoint, check the value, and see what makes `decimal.Parse` throw you an error.